# cannot move uploaded files failed to open stream

Tags: php

Hello so i have a simple upload system in php and i want to upload my files to ftp server but when i try to it doesnt work i get these two errors:

**Warning: move_uploaded_file(/userfiles/grega): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/disk3/1618233/www/netdisk.co.nf/upload.php on line 19**

**Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpVtApVM' to '/userfiles/grega' in /srv/disk3/1618233/www/netdisk.co.nf/upload.php on line 19**

and there is folder **userfiles/grega** on the ftp server please help me out

the code:

```
<?php

require_once 'core/init.php';
if($_POST[submit]) {
    $name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $temp = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $type = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
    $size = $_FILES['upload']['size'];

    if($size <= 5000000){

        $user = new User();

        if(!$user->isLoggedIn()) {
            Redirect::to('index.php');
        }
        $uploads_dir = '/userfiles';
        $username = ($user->data()->username);
        move_uploaded_file($temp,"$uploads_dir/$username");
        Session::flash('home', '<h3>Datoteka je bila naložena!</h3>');
        Redirect::to('mojprofil.php');
    } else{
        echo "Napaka!";
    }
} else {
    header("Location: mojprofil.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: You aren't giving the file a name? `"$uploads_dir/$username"` is the directory right? But you need to put a filename there too.

Comment: yes it does exists i've saved other stuff before so i guess it is writable

Answer (score 1):

You say this:

> there is folder userfiles/grega

But the error says this:

> move_uploaded_file(/userfiles/grega)

Those are two *very* (even if subtly) different paths.  Note also where you define the path in your code:

```
$uploads_dir = '/userfiles';
```

The code is looking for a folder called `userfiles` in the root of *the entire file system*, not just in the website.  Perhaps you meant to do this?:

```
$uploads_dir = 'userfiles';
```

Comment: @user3389744: Define "doesn't work."  What is the runtime value of the full pathname/filename of the destination file?  Does that entire path exist on the server?  Is it writable?  Is it writable *by the PHP user context*?  There's a lot of information you can gather here.

Comment: `/srv/disk3/1618233/www/netdisk.co.nf/userfiles/grega` thats the whole path and by doesn't work-it directed me to an 403 error webpage